# Converting a string of an array into an array in JS

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a project I'm working on that implements MySQL, React and Express.js. I need to save an array into MySQL, but there are currently no ways to save an array, as far as I could see, so I was forced to convert it into a string. When I get it back from Express to the client, it's obviously a string, so I can't access the data. This array is used for a graph, mainly. What are some of the ways I can convert this string back to an array?

Comment: Can you please provide code sample of the string you store? And have you considered saving the array's elements in a different table and use many-to-one relation?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `JSON.parse()` to convert a string into an array.

```js
const response = "[1,2,3]";

console.log(JSON.parse(response));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store your `json object (including arrays )`in form of `text` in mysql database.What you have to do is `JSON.stringify("your array")` and persist it in database.And while you are retrieving it back from database you can `JSON.parse()` to get it in form of JavaScript object

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you formed the string. If you used `,` for joining the elements, then you can use javascript's `string.split()` method.

```
let str = '1,2,3,4';
let arr = str.split(',');
```

Just pass in whatever delimiter you used to join the elements.

### OR

If you're saving elements as a json string, then use `JSON.parse(str)` as shown by Nils Kähler in his answer